# How to autoresize the button

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a custom view contain NSImageView (myImageView) and NSButton (myButton). When user resize window (using mouse click and drag in bottom right corner of window), myImageView and myButton is autoresized. But custom view is unlike orginal. How to fix it? Please help me.

Here is my code:

In appDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application 
[window makeKeyWindow];
[window setFrameTopLeftPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 576)];
[window setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 768, 576) display:YES];

[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[window center];

TestView *testView = [[TestView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 768, 576)];
[testView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
[testView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[window setContentView:testView];}
```

In TestView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
// Drawing code here.
NSImageView *subView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 768, 576)];
[subView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Copenhagen.jpg"]];
[subView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
[subView setImageScaling:NSImageScaleProportionallyDown];
[self addSubview:subView];
[subView release];

NSButton *subButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(70, 100, 100, 40)];
[subButton setTitle:@"Click"];
[subButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewMaxXMargin|NSViewMaxYMargin|NSViewMinXMargin|NSViewMinYMargin];
[self addSubview:subButton];
[subButton release];
[window setContentView:temp];}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you set an autoresizing mask for your custom view? You can do that either in Interface Builder or programatically via `-[NSView setAutoresizingMask:]`.

Comment: I have already set autoresizing mask for my custom view, myImageView and myButton, but myButton looks like unlike orginal when autoresizing

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean. Maybe a screenshot would make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: Here is two picture showing what I want:  [before autoresizing](http://img01.imagecanon.com/img.php?view=1eef9e385f3517eb26efa22bbebb6e3e),and [after autoresizing](http://img01.imagecanon.com/img.php?view=cf261cb4c67e725073d4aaf9aa83a516)

Comment: And the problem is that the button is being resized, or placed with different margins, or both?

Comment: The button is placed with different margins

Comment: And how are you setting the autoresizing mask? Via Interface Builder or programatically? If it’s programatically, could you edit your question and post the code you’re using?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t want the left margin (`NSViewMinXMargin`) and the bottom margin (`NSViewMinYMargin`) to be flexible, so you should remove those from the button’s autoresizing mask. You probably don’t want the button itself to be resized so, in fact, use only

```
NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMaxYMargin
```

as the autoresizing mask.

The [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html) is a good reference to learn about autoresizing masks.

Comment: I have removed them. But later I resize the window, it becomes like this: [image](http://img01.imagecanon.com/img.php?view=231ff92b0178ab6b1fc3be653709b23a)

Comment: @user Do you want the button to be resized at all? If not, remove `NSViewWidthSizable` and `NSViewHeightSizable` from the autoresizing mask.